# Excel Conditional Formatting using Search

Tags: excel, function, search, formatting, conditional-statements

Okay so I need some more help. I am trying to use conditional formatting to put a strike through when the name in the box is put in the list above. Like shown below

[image: Picture of what I am trying to do]

So as you can see above the 3 names below are put into a layout shown above, As they are put into a class I would like to use Conditional Formatting to put a strike through. I tried this formula:

```
=SEARCH(C10:C30,C3:C9)
```

This only works if the names in the box are put into each class in the same order as the box, except I can't do it that way I need to be able to jumble them into different classes and as I put them in I was hoping to put a strike through in the box to keep track.

For Barry Houdini:

[image: As you can see I did exactly what you said, including using the formula you told me to use]

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to your example, you can use Excel VLOOKUP function like shown below:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C10,C$3:C$9, 1, TRUE), FALSE)
```

for cell C10, then extend it to the entire range of interest, i.e., cell C11 will contain the formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C11,C$3:C$9, 1, TRUE), FALSE)
```

and so on.

Regards,

Comment: I can't put a formula in the cells because there is already one there, I want to use conditional formatting to put a strikethrough the names as there put into the table. What you have here looks like something that should be put in each cell which I can't do.

Comment: Well, in this case you can try the SEARCH()-based solution that @barry houdini mentioned: notice, that you can use an absolute reference C$3:C$9 (no need to add $C as you do not extend the formula horizontally), as shown in my example. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

`SEARCH` should work OK, but you need to make the search range absolute......and you only need to use the cell reference of the **first** cell in your conditional formatting range, i.e. apply this formula in conditional formatting - with "Applies to" set to the range `C10:C30`

`=SEARCH(C10,$C$3:$C$9)`

Edit:

As per my comment below, sorry above doesn't work - use COUNTIF with wildcards like

`=COUNTIF(C$3:C$9,"*"&C10&"*")`

Comment: I tried this already and it still only works for the first name, C10, does this mean I need to make another rule each name, because its only using the name in C10 instead of the whole range of names that I needed ergo I had C10:C30

Comment: No you only need one rule but you need to "apply" the rule to the whole range that might be formatted, when you set up conditional formatting you can enter the formula and then you have an "Applies to" range - enter the formula I suggested and set the "Applies to" range to C10:C30 or whatever you require - Note that if you select the range first it will default to the range you select

Comment: Yes I did that, I put =SEARCH(C10,C$3:C$9) with a applies to range of C10:C30 but it still only works for the C10 cell because its searching for the String in C10 over and over rather then looking for C10, then C11, then C12, etc.

Comment: No, that's not the way it works, as long as you use C10 in the formula (with no $ signs) then Excel knows that it should adjust each row to C11, C12 etc. - let me set up an example........

Comment: Okay maybe if you show me I will understand where I messed up.

Comment: Sorry, I have been misleading you! SEARCH won't work here - try using COUNTIF like this: `=COUNTIF(C$3:C$9,"*"&C10&"*")` - SEARCH will adjust as I said but will only apply to first cell of C3:C9, hence no good - I'll change my answer accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58577/discussion-between-brent-and-barry-houdini).